# Problema con la posición de una lista en python

Tags: python, lista

¡Hola!
He intentado crear un contador de palabras en una lista de textos. El objetivo es que el contador muestre el resultado de si ha encontrado o no la palabra en cada texto por separado (de momento sólo he conseguido que muestre la suma de las búsquedas) para así luego crear una tabla en la que las filas sean los textos y las columnas las palabras de la lista "palabra". Otro problema que he tenido es que estoy intentado que si en el texto ponga "no tiene cefalea" no se cuente como que ha encontrado la palabra cefalea. Para eso he añadido que si encuentra la palabra en el texto, cree un fragmento desde unas palabras antes a la palabra encontrada a unas palabras después y que si encuentra una de las palabras de lista_excluir, no sume al contador, mientras que si no encuentra ninguna de estas palabras en el fragmento, sume al contador.
Sin embargo, me devuelve este error en la línea "if lista_excluir[p] in fragmento:"  "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"
¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
 palabra = ["cefalea", "hemicraneal", "días", "dormir"]
 hc = "cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
 hc2 = "Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
 texto = [hc,hc2]
 lista_excluir = ["no", "ausencia", "ausente", "ni", "tampoco"]
 contador=[0, 0, 0, 0,]

for i in range(len(palabra)):
    for j in range(len(texto)):
        if palabra[i] in texto[j].split():
           texto_encontrado=texto[j].split() 
           posicion_palabra=texto_encontrado.index(palabra[i])
           parada_anterior = posicion_palabra - 3
           parada_posterior = posicion_palabra + 2
           fragmento=texto_encontrado[parada_anterior:parada_posterior]
           for p in lista_excluir:
               if lista_excluir[p] in fragmento:
                   contador[i]+=0
               else:
                   contador[i]+=1

print(contador)
```

Comment: Daniel quieres el contador por cada texto, pero ¿el contador debe decir si la palabra está o no en el texto simplemente o debe contar las veces que aparece en cada texto (suponiendo que se pueda repetir dentro de un mismo texto)? Por otro lado, ¿las palabras de lista excluir se aplican a todas las palbras a buscar o solo a cefalea? En cuanto al error, `for p in lista_excluir:` ya te retorna las palabras, no indexes el `if`, simplemente: `if p in fragmento:`

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, querría que el contador dijera si la palabra aparece en cada texto, no me interesa saber cuántas veces aparece o no. Las palabras de la lista excluir se aplicarían a todas las palabras a buscar (lo que intento es que solo sumen las frases afirmativas).

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos errores en tu código:

- El primero es el ya comentado, `for p in lista_excluir` ya retorna la palabra por lo que el indexado no tiene sentido:

  ```
  for p in lista_excluir:
      if lista_excluir[p] in fragmento:
  ```
- El otro se encuentra en el slicing para obtener el fragmento:

  ```
  parada_anterior = posicion_palabra - 3
  ```

  Si posición_palabra es menor de 3 el ídice resultante es negativo. Python acepta índices negativos pero el resultado no es el que tu quieres:

  ```
  >>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
  >>> l[-2:3]
  ['c']
  ```

Sin apartarse mucho de tu código puedes hacer algo así:

```
from pprint import pprint

palabras = ["cefalea", "hemicraneal", "días", "dormir"]
hc = "cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
hc2 = "Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
hc3 = "Hombre con cefalea ausente ni ganas de dormir"


lista_excluir = ["no", "ausencia", "ausente", "ni", "tampoco"]
textos = [hc,hc2, hc3]
contador=[]

for texto in textos:
    palabras_texto = texto.split()
    aux = {p: False for p in palabras}
    for palabra in palabras:
        try:
            index = palabras_texto.index(palabra)
            fragmento = palabras_texto[max(index - 3, 0):index + 2]
            if not any(excluida in fragmento for excluida in lista_excluir):
                aux[palabra] = True
        except ValueError: continue
    contador.append(aux)

pprint(contador)
```

**La salida es:**

> ```
> [{'cefalea': True, 'dormir': False, 'días': True, 'hemicraneal': True},
>  {'cefalea': True, 'dormir': True, 'días': False, 'hemicraneal': False},
>  {'cefalea': False, 'dormir': False, 'días': False, 'hemicraneal': False}]
> ```

Por cada texto tienes un diccionario indicando si una palabra se encuentra en la lista (y cumple con las excluisones) o no. El resultado se muestra con un boleano (`True` si la palabra está y `False` si no lo está). Es muy simple hacer que en vez de un dicionario sea una lista o que en vez de boleanos ea enteros (0 y 1).

Si quieres construir una matriz basta con hacer algo como:

```
tabla = [[cont_texto[palabra] for palabra in palabras]  for cont_texto in contador]
pprint(tabla)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> [[True, True, True, False],
>  [True, False, False, True],
>  [False, False, False, False]]
> ```

Donde cada fila es un texto (en el orden en el que aparecen en la lista `textos`) y cada columna una palabra (en el orden en el que aparecen en al lista `palabras`).

> Nota: Al usar 3 y 2 para el slicing al obtener `fragmento` tienes en cuenta 3 palabras anteriores y **una** posterior.

Comment: Ups no me había dado cuenta de esos errores. Muchísimas gracias por la corrección y tus explicaciones, funciona al 100% como buscaba. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque p ya es el elemento que buscas, no un indice.

Como sugerencias:

- usa print para ver lo que pasa
- no es bueno meterse en bucles tan complejos
- parte el problema en trocitos mas manejables

Ejemplo:

```
palabra = ["cefalea", "hemicraneal", "días", "dormir"]
lista_excluir = ["no", "ausencia", "ausente", "ni", "tampoco"]
max_anteriores = 2

hc = "cefalea hemicraneal derecha de 4 días de evolución"
hc2 = "Hombre con cefalea y ganas de dormir"
hc3 = "Hombre con ausencia de cefalea y ni ganas de dormir"
texto = [hc,hc2, hc3]

def excluyen(anteriores):
    """ Hay palabras que excluyen en esta lista?
    """
    for x in anteriores:
        if x in lista_excluir: return True
    return False

def palabras_en(texto):
    """ Devuelve lista encontradas en texto
    """
    encontradas = []
    anteriores = []
    for p in texto.split():
        cuenta = p in palabra and not excluyen(anteriores) 
        #print "%s %s -> %s" % (anteriores, p, "SI" if cuenta else "NO")
        if cuenta and not p in encontradas: encontradas.append(p)
        anteriores.append(p)
        if len(anteriores)>max_anteriores: del anteriores[0]
    return encontradas


for t in texto:
    print t
    encontradas = palabras_en(t)
    print encontradas
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por aportar esta solución, funciona perfectamente, pero como soy principiante me siento más cómodo utilizando la versión de FJSevilla que se aparta menos de mi código original. Muchas gracias!